# How to get these values front end using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Date:
             
            model.Date) %>--%> // Should I use this as Input type?
            
            
                Number#:
                
            
            Comment

I am trying to get these three fields on the screen while user enters I am retreving the user enter data on front end.. when I am debugging I am not seeing these fields..

On the view I am using beginForm

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "id" }))
   { %>
```

my method..

```
public JsonResult Update(StudentInfo info)
{
  ///Update
  return Json(Status.ToString()); 
}
```

when I see in info I am not getting these three fields..

can any one help me out thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a description of exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to make those three fields as input fields.. and I am trying to get those fileds on front end to update. 

should I use Html.EidtorFor ? or should I use Input textbox to get the values?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a JsonResult but doing as Http post (Html.BeginForm). If you want to use a full form post then return a ActionResult.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Add action logic here
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call void controller

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense that you're returning a JsonResult from a HTML Post.

Do this instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(StudentInfo info)
{
  ///Update
  if (updateWorked)
    return View("Success", status);
}
```

You use JsonResult when you want to call a controller that returns JSON data, in order to display this data somewhere on your page.

A useful scenario for JsonResult in your scenario would be returning a json list of Students, executed from a click event maybe (call in JavaScript/jQuery).

Calling an action method on a HTTP Post which returns a JsonResult of a single string (not real JSON) makes no sense.